# accessing parent classes name while naming child classname in SASS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, node-sass

```
.project{
  $self=&;
.card{
  #{$self}__name{
     font-weight:bold;
  }
.card__body{
     display:flex
  }
  }}
```

I want to add classname "card__body" with variable something like $self but here $self denotes "project" instead of hardcoding "card__body". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

we need to use interpolation in sass using `&` and `#{&}`
we are using second `&` inside `#{}` because we cannot use `&&`

```
.project{
  $self=&;
  .card{
   #{$self}__name{
     font-weight:bold;
   }
   & #{&}_body{     //this will result in '.card .card_body{ }'
     display:flex;
   }

   &_body{     //this will result in '.card_body{ }' without parent nesting
     display:flex;
   }
 }
}
```

get more details on [sass interpolation here on official docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation)